# Combine redundant legends produced by ggplot geom_point and geom_line plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to demonstrate differences between two groups with geom_point and errorbars, and link them by geom_line so it is easy to follow which groups are linked. The legend produced automatically contains 2 panels, one for the points, and one for the lines. I've searched for "combine legends" and "redundant legends" and numerous other things, and have gotten close a time or two, but can't seem to resolve my issue. I'd like to have a single legend showing both the point and line types, but I'd settle for just dropping the line legend and showing the points. As far as the code goes, I'm fairly novice, so if you see ways to be more efficient, I'm happy to learn. Thanks for any assistance.

```
dat <- structure(list(pop = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), foundlost = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Found", "Lost"), class = "factor"), 
mean = c(3.939, -7.153, 3.001, -4.089, 4.247, -5.168), sd = c(4.394, 
9.08, 4.627, 6.644, 5.346, 6.592), Freq = c(118L, 65L, 109L, 
80L, 202L, 166L), error = c(0.792806386453774, 2.20738080265164, 
0.868629033901147, 1.4559039398977, 0.737227217957054, 1.00279288913615
), Edn = c(3.14619361354623, -9.36038080265164, 2.13237096609885, 
-5.5449039398977, 3.50977278204295, -6.17079288913615), Eup = c(4.73180638645377, 
-4.94561919734836, 3.86962903390115, -2.6330960601023, 4.98422721795705, 
-4.16520711086385)), .Names = c("pop", "foundlost", "mean", 
"sd", "Freq", "error", "Edn", "Eup"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
dat

attach(dat)
require(ggplot2)
pd <- position_dodge(.2)


mainplot <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=foundlost, y=mean, ymin=Edn, ymax=Eup, linetype=NULL, group=pop)) +
geom_point(aes(shape=pop), size=4, position=pd)+
geom_errorbar(width=0.2, size=1.25, position=pd)+
geom_line(position=pd, size=1.25, aes(group=pop, linetype=pop))

phase2 <- mainplot +
scale_shape_discrete(name="", labels= c("ONE", "TWO", "TREE"))+
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.1,0.1)) +
labs(title="Mean standardized differences",
        y="Deviation from population mean",
        x="")

phase2 + 
theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5)), 
panel.background=element_blank(),
axis.line=element_line(1.5),
panel.grid=element_blank(), 
axis.text=element_text(colour='black', size=14), 
axis.title.y=element_text(colour='black', size=14),
axis.ticks=element_line(colour='black', size=1),
legend.position=c(.2,.25),

complete=FALSE)
```

Edit for final point: I realize from my reading that this has to do with the way I've set up my aes() or something, and the fact they don't match, but everything I've tried has failed so far, thus my query to the ggroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things going on here with your legends.

First, you were getting two legends due to the `linetype = NULL` argument in the overall plot `aes`.  Removing that gets rid of the two legends initially.  But then a second legend gets added again with the use of `scale_shape_discrete`.  You will need to use both `scale_shape_discrete` and `scale_linetype_discrete` if you want to change legend labels this way and have a single legend.  There is a good example of this on the *Legends* page of the [Cookbook for R website](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/).

I think one of the easiest ways to change legend labels is to simply set the levels of the factor `pop` in the dataset before plotting.

```
levels(dat$pop) = c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE")
```

If you use a combined legend, you might want to change the width of the legend to show the linetype better, though, which you can do in `guides` with `guide_legend` and `keywidth` as I show below.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=foundlost, y=mean, ymin=Edn, ymax=Eup, group=pop)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=pop), size=4, position=pd) +
    geom_errorbar(width=0.2, size=1.25, position=pd) +
    geom_line(position=pd, size=1, aes(group=pop, linetype=pop)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.1,0.1)) +
    labs(title="Mean standardized differences",
        y="Deviation from population mean",
        x="") + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5)), 
         panel.background=element_blank(),
         axis.line=element_line(1.5),
         panel.grid=element_blank(), 
         axis.text=element_text(colour='black', size=14), 
         axis.title.y=element_text(colour='black', size=14),
         axis.ticks=element_line(colour='black', size=1),
         legend.position=c(.2,.25)) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(keywidth = 2))
```

To remove the `linetype` legend instead, use `show.legend = FALSE` when adding the `geom_line` layer.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=foundlost, y=mean, ymin=Edn, ymax=Eup, group=pop)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=pop), size=4, position=pd) +
    geom_errorbar(width=0.2, size=1.25, position=pd) +
    geom_line(position=pd, size=1, aes(group=pop, linetype=pop), show_guide = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Everything seems to almost get me there, but when I run it all together as you've posted, there's an unclosed parenthesis. When I close it, I throw the error: "Error in c(0.2, 0.25) + guides(shape = guide_legend(keywidth = 2)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator". I played around with it, and if I run the ggplot and guides call only, that part works, but when I try to adjust themes, it seems to go awry. Thanks again. You guys do a huge service.

Comment: @A.Birdman Ah, yep, I dropped a parenthesis when making an edit.  Added.

Comment: I played around a bit more and found that simply positioning the guides() call between the ggplot and themes made it run fine.